# Isochronous endpoint descriptor service interval choice

Tags: usb, usb-device

Here's the isochronous endpoint descriptor:

```
0x07,                           /* Descriptor size */
CY_U3P_USB_ENDPNT_DESCR,        /* Endpoint descriptor type */
CONSUMER_ENDPOINT,              /* Endpoint address and description */
CY_U3P_USB_EP_ISO,              /* Iso endpoint type */
0x00,0x04,                      /* Max packet size = 1024 bytes */
0x04,                           /* Servicing interval for data transfers: 1ms*/
```

The last argument is the servicing interval. Currently, it is 0x04 meaning that the polling period is 8, that is, every eights bus interval. I know I can set such interval with values 0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04 meaning every microFrame, every second, every fourth, and every eights microframe respectively. Would it be possible to have a 0x8 interval to have polling on every 16th microframe (every second frame)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of 5 gives you 2^(5-1)=2^4=16.Period for High-speed will be 16*0.125 = 2ms. So this specifies desirable interval between every 16th micro-frame.

To get a period you need to multiply the resulting value to 0.125ms or to 1ms, depending on the speed of your USB-bus.

Answer (score 1):

The USB specification (2.0) says about `bInterval`:

> For full-/high-speed isochronous endpoints, this value
>   must be in the range from 1 to 16.

So you could have an interval of up to 32768 microframes.

Comment: For Full speed the value is always 1 right? And for HS or SS it can range from 1-16?

Comment: The specification allows full-speed *isochronous* endpoints to have intervals larger than 1.

Comment: Right, this makes sense.